# Installing Ubuntu in external HD (dual boot) and without the necessity of turning off my windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, nvidia, shutdown

I would like to know if is possible to create a dual boot without the necessity of turning of the windows.

Explaining:

Recently i tried to install a Ubuntu in my windows machine, and i was having some trouble to install the nvidia driver, so my ubuntu was freezing, and the only possible way to turn off the computer was pressing the power button (i was forcing the shut down)... and as everybody know.. this could mess with my hardware... the idea is install the ubuntu without compromising all the machine... so if the ubuntu freezes i could start again without a forcible shut down.

Thanks.

Comment: Hard shut-downs and reboots don't damage your hardware (unless it's already faulty, e. g. like with cheap or damaged power supply). However they will likely corrupt the data structures on active file systems. Fortunately most of the damage from that is mitigated in modern file systems (through so-called "journals") so that you only stand to loose data that was currently or very recently manipulated.

Answer (score 0):

When you dual boot, GRUB is giving you a choice of running Ubuntu or Windows. If you choose Ubuntu, Windows does not start up, therefore you cannot turn Windows off.

Therefore, you have to solve the Ubuntu problems from within Ubuntu. Windows isn't available to take over in a system lockup.

Comment: That's sad.. so i need take the risk of f* the hardware...

Comment: Why do you think turning off the computer ruins the hardware?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have two systems running at once, they both want exclusively manage your hardware.

But maybe you want to run Linux in a virtual machine? How to do that in Windows is off topic here, but take a look at [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) for example. This software enables you to run a second (or more) systems on your current Windows (or Linux) installation in a window or full screen.

Last but not least, normal computer *hardware* isn't affected by a forced shutdown, filesystems (software) are the only thing I can think of that might take damage.